# Calling a method before or after each @POST or @DELETE request in JAX-RS

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

Is there any method or annotation in JAX-RS that allows me to call a method before or after the matching request method is executed. Lets assume I have the following service class:

```
public class MyService {

    ...

    @POST
    @Path("{id : \\d+}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response updateServiceObject(@PathParam("id") long id, InputStream is) {
        try {
            // Fetch the service object ...
            ServiceObject updatedServiceObj = readServiceObject(is);

            // ... and try to update it.
            updated = getServiceObjectDao().update(updatedServiceObj);

            if (updated == 0) {
                throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
            }

            return Response.ok().build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id : \\d+}")
    public Response deleteServiceObject(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        try {
            getServiceObjectDao().deleteById(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

I would like to add a method `logEvent()`, which logs which method has been called and which parameters (just @PathParam values) had been provided. So it has to bee invoked before or after each call.

Comment: you can have filters or interceptors. Also some frameworks have built in support for logging. What framework is yours ?

Comment: I am using Apache CXF.

Comment: What version of JAX-RS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect fit for aspects or filters.  Filters are HTTP aspects.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your cxf xml.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:features>
            <cxf:logging/>
        </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus> 
</beans>
```

Ref :  http://cxf.apache.org/docs/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

In this page https://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-filters.html explains how to implement interceptors and filters for CXF with JAX-RS.

Answer (score -4):

use Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP)

Comment: what is AOP? can you explain or can give link related to this